# Существует ли в Spring упрощенный вариант описания REST клиента

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

Доброе время суток.

Описание серверной стороны:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/MyEntity")
public class MyEntityController {

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityServer myEntityService;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public MyEntity getEntityById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return myEntityService.findOneById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getEntityById2")
    public MyEntity getEntityById2(Integer id) {
        return myEntityService.findOneById(id);
    }

}
```

Описание клиентской стороны предсавляет собой примерно следующие:

```
@Service
public class MyEntityService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public MyEntity getEntityById(Integer id) {
        return restTemplate.getForObject("/MyEntity/{id}", MyEntity.class, id);
    }

    // или по имени метода в чистом виде (кто как контоллер описывает)

    public MyEntity getEntityById2(Integer id) {
        return restTemplate.getForObject("/MyEntity/getEntityById2?id=" + id, MyEntity.class);
    }

}
```

Вопрос:
Есть ли что нибудь из готового что позволит использовать примерно следующий вариант:

```
// common-api 

@RequestMapping("/MyEntity")
public interface MyEntityApi {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public MyEntity getEntityById(@PathVariable Integer id);

    @GetMapping("/getEntityById2")
    public MyEntity getEntityById2(Integer id);

}

// server
// тут не знаю, нужны ли аннотации или нет об этой стороне сильно не задумывался

@RestController
public class MyEntityController implements MyEntityApi {

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityServer myEntityService;

    @Override
    public MyEntity getEntityById(Integer id) {
        return myEntityService.findOneById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public MyEntity getEntityById2(Integer id) {
        return myEntityService.findOneById(id);
    }

}

// client

@SpringRESTClientSide
// где @SpringRESTClientSide то что я ищу
public interface MyEntityService implements MyEntityApi {}
```

Т.е. что бы spring (по аналогии CRUDRepository) сам создавал бины по интерфейсу. Ведь все данные для запроса он имеет: по аннтоации можно узнать тип запроса и путь (`@RequestMapping("/MyEntity")` + `@GetMapping("/{id})` и т.д), то же касается параметров и возвращаемого типа.

Comment: пока не совсем пойму что именно Вам нужно. по описанию кажется что Вы хотите пользоваться своим же Rest-сервисом и упростить процесс именно с учетом использования своего сервиса... RestTemplate  создавался для общего использования, без каких-либо ограничения на расположение сервиса и в данном контексте я его нахожу достаточно удобным. Пока что ничего другого я в спринге не видел, однако, никто не мешает написать обёртку, которая будет предоставлять все необходимые методы для работы с сервисом.

Comment: описанию того что Вам нужно соответствует другой продукт (не спринговый), которым я тоже достаточно часто пользуюсь. это [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). Он может строить клиент на основе интерфейса и аннотаций. Удобная штука.